# Authorization header doesn't work with http GET requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm using VueSession in my project. I created a login component and I'm passing data to my backend (Django, returns JWT token). Here is my problem. My login works fine, it returns JWT but when I want to get data from other endpoints I'm getting error 401 (`Authentication credentials were not provided`). When I'm using curl in my terminal everything works fine.

`curl -X POST -d "username=test&password=test" http://localhost:8000/api/token/auth/`

it returns token

`curl -H "Authorization: JWT <my_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/`

and it returns data from website

Here is what I set up in my Vue project.

`Login.vue`

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data () {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    login: function (username, password) {
      let user_obj = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
      }
      this.$http.post('http://192.168.1.151:8000/api/token/auth', user_obj)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.$session.start()
        this.$session.set('jwt', response.data.token)
        Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT' + response.data.token

        // this.$router.push('/')

      })
      .catch((error_data) => {
        console.log(error_data)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`HereIWantUserGETRequest.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome",
      my_list: []
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    // IF SESSION DOESN'T EXIST
    if (!this.$session.exists()) {
      this.$router.push('/account/login')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://192.168.1.151:8000/api/user/data')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
          this.my_list = response.data
        })
        .catch((error_data) => {
          console.log(error_data)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And of course I set up VueSession and VueResource in main.js

```
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueSession)
```

Comment: `Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT' + response.data.token` is missing a **space** after JWT.

Comment: Have you though about using the axios library?

Comment: @PatrickCyiza Yeah I tried it but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line `Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.token`. To fix it I needed to at this to my main.js file:

```
if (this.$session.exists()) {
      var token = this.$session.get('jwt')
      console.log(token)
      Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + token
}
```

And now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Edit

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT' + response.data.token
```

with

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.token
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the help but it works only once when I refresh the page I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually store your jwt token anywhere in your browser (with a cookie or a localStorage). Therefore Vue has the token in memory only for the runtime of that page (in the sense of a one page app) you've request your jwt token in. According to the [github docs of VueSession](https://github.com/victorsferreira/vue-session) the option to store the token in your browser is false by default. Just set it to true like this:

```
#main.js

var options = {
  persist: true
}

Vue.use(VueSession, options)
```

I personally don't use this library. I usually do it from scratch using axios, Vuex and localStorage. It's really not that difficult, the pattern is described pretty well [here](https://blog.sqreen.io/authentication-best-practices-vue/).

Comment: You should try to follow the alternatif solution I've linked in my answer. If you are already familiar with vuex, you'll be up and running in less then half an hour.